# Concatenate flattened layers with Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm having a hard time making a model to fit. I'm not sure if it is an input problem or a model problem. It looks like the concatenate layer is at fault, but after flattening all layers, concatenation should have been ok, no? My guess is it's about the `sec_input / sec_flatten` layers, since it's works if I remove them.

```
tf.__version__: '2.12.0'
```

1 - I'm getting this error on `model.fit(sg_train, epochs=100)`:

```
Exception has occurred: InvalidArgumentError
Graph execution error:
(...)
Node: 'gradient_tape/conv2D_3_inputs/concat/ConcatOffset'
All dimensions except 1 must match. Input 2 has shape [32 1] and doesn't match input 0 with shape [1 936].
     [[{{node gradient_tape/conv2D_3_inputs/concat/ConcatOffset}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_2217]
```

2 - This is my model:

```
nat_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(
    shape=(window, nat_col_len, spectrum_layers), name="nat_input"
)
nat_conv_1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
    conv_filters, kernel_1, activation="relu", padding=padding, name="nat_conv_1"
)(nat_input)
nat_batch_norm_1 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(nat_conv_1)
nat_pooling_1 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), name="nat_pooling_1")(
    nat_batch_norm_1
)
nat_conv_2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
    conv_filters, kernel_1, activation="relu", padding=padding, name="nat_conv_2"
)(nat_pooling_1)
nat_batch_norm_2 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(nat_conv_2)
nat_pooling_2 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), name="nat_pooling_2")(
    nat_conv_2
)
nat_flatten = tf.keras.layers.Flatten(name="nat_flatten")(nat_pooling_2)


act_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(
    shape=(window, act_col_len, spectrum_layers), name="act_input"
)
act_conv_1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
    conv_filters, kernel_1, activation="relu", padding=padding, name="act_conv_1"
)(act_input)
act_batch_norm_1 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(act_conv_1)
act_pooling_1 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), name="act_pooling_1")(
    act_batch_norm_1
)
act_conv_2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
    conv_filters, kernel_1, activation="relu", padding=padding, name="act_conv_2"
)(act_pooling_1)
act_batch_norm_2 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(act_conv_2)
act_pooling_2 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), name="act_pooling_2")(
    act_conv_2
)
act_flatten = tf.keras.layers.Flatten(name="act_flatten")(act_pooling_2)

sec_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(window, 1), name="sec_input")
sec_flatten = tf.keras.layers.Flatten(name="sec_flatten")(sec_input)

concat = tf.keras.layers.concatenate(
    [nat_flatten, act_flatten, sec_flatten], name="concat"
)
dense_1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu", name="dense_1")(concat)
dropout_1 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2, name="dropout_1")(dense_1)
ouput = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, name="output")(dropout_1)

model = tf.keras.Model(
    inputs=[nat_input, act_input, sec_input],
    outputs=ouput,
    name="conv2D_3_inputs",
)

model.compile(
    optimizer="adam",
    loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(),
    metrics=["mae", tf.keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError()],
)
```

[image]

3 - And this is my inputs shapes (one sample), from a generator:

```
# X_train_nat_i.shape: (1, 32, 470, 1)
# X_train_act_i.shape: (1, 32, 480, 1)
# X_train_sec_i.shape: (32,)
# y_train_i.shape: (1,)

return (X_train_nat_i, X_train_act_i, X_train_sec_i), y_train_i
```

It's certainly a stupid mistake. I hope you will spot it. Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: it says all dims of shape must match except for one. have you tried inverting the `[32, 1]` shaped array to `[1, 32]`? That will match one dim with the `[1, 936]` array

Comment: Well, it looks like it works, but I don't understand why. Shouldn't the input shapes in the `concat` layers be  [(None, 936), (None, 960), (None, 32)]?

Comment: That is what happening when you are reshaping `[32, 1]` to `[1, 32]` as it matches the first dimension with the other inputs. It considers the first dimension as `batch_size` which is why when you run `model.summary()` it shows `[(None, 936), (None, 960), (None, 32)]`, where `None` represents the variable `batch_size`.

Comment: Anyway, thank you! Feel free to add an official answer, I will gladly accept it.